# Webpack bundle does not show css

Tags: html, css, django, webpack

I had a Django with Bootstrap working fine before. I am trying to get this up and running (without the react part) with Webpack following this:
http://owaislone.org/blog/webpack-plus-reactjs-and-django/

The bundle is made when I run the webpack script. In the browser I keep getting plain html and so the bundle is not used...

Relevant code

testhtml.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>This is my fantastic demo!!!</title>
</head>
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}

{% render_bundle 'main' %}
<body>
<div>"how about this?"</div>

</body>
</html>
```

webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');`enter code here`
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var Clean = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
var bootstrapPath = path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    context: __dirname,
    entry: './assets/js/index', // entry point of our app. .assets/js/index.js should require other js modules and dependencies it needs
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./assets/bundles/'),
        filename: '[name]-[hash].js'
    },
    node: {
        console: true,
        fs: 'empty'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery'
        }),
        new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}),
        new webpack.BannerPlugin('Banner!!!! todo'),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: __dirname + '/assets/index.tmpl.html'
        }),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new Clean(['assets/bundles'])
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js[x]?$/,
                loader: 'babel',
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower-components)/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: 'json-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/mapbox-gl/js/render/shaders.js'),
                loader: 'transform/cacheable?brfs'
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/webworkify/index.js'),
                loader: 'worker'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style!css?modules!postcss'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap', 'sass?sourceMap']
            },
            /*
             {
             test: /\.woff$/,
             loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff&name=[path][name].[ext]'
             }, {
             test: /\.woff2$/,
             loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff2&name=[path][name].[ext]'
             }, {
             test: /\.(eot|ttf|svg|gif|png)$/,
             loader: 'file-loader'
             }
             */
            {test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?2?$/, loader: 'url-loader'},
            {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader'},
            {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader'},
            {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader'}
        ]
    },
    postcss: [
        require('autoprefixer')
    ],
    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'bower_components', bootstrapPath],
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.css'],
        alias: {
            webworkify: 'webworkify-webpack',
            '$': 'jquery',
            'jQuery': 'jquery'
        }
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './assets',
        colors: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        inline: true,
        hot: true
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was importing (equivalent of require under ES6) a plugin which apparently caused issues. After leaving that plugin out the django-webloader-loader worked as expected. For more detail, see:
https://github.com/owais/django-webpack-loader/issues/51

Answer (score 0):

Did you require the css files?

Using the css and style loaders you [embed the css files](https://webpack.github.io/docs/stylesheets.html) in the Webpack bundle, requiring them as you would do with any other module.

If you look in the Webpack documentation I linked you'll see:

```
// in your modules just require the stylesheet 
// This has the side effect that a <style>-tag is added to the DOM.
require("./stylesheet.css");// This has the side effect that a <style>-tag is added to the DOM.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will give a detailed answer which solved my issue.